# Plain html not working with struts

Tags: html, jsp, struts

I'm trying out two things here: firstly, running a normal jsp with action as helloWorld.do :

```
<html:form action="helloWorld.do" method="post">
```

and the same thing in html too:

```
<form action="helloWorld.do" method="post">
<input type="text" name="userName"> <!-- userName and password names do match the variables in form -->
<input type="password" name="password">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

When I run the jsp, the action in the jsp maps to the right action and renders the page correctly but with html it actually calls `http://localhost/StrutsExample/helloworld.do`. Here helloWorld.do changed to helloworld.do. So, it rendered an empty page (this is the page I'm trying to display the username) So, I tried to add a new action in struts :

```
<action path="/helloworld"
    type="com.org.common.action.HWdAction"
    name="hWForm">
    <forward name="success" path="/HW.jsp"/>
</action>
```

It still does not work. The form does not populate itself with the name entered in html.

Comment: Doesn't configured a form bean?

Answer (score 0):

By default, if not specified, the method used by a `html:form` tag of Struts 1.x is `POST`. No need to add the  `.do`, neither add the initial diagonal, `/`.

```
<html:form action="helloWorld">
```

However, if you use the simple `form` tag of HTML, you need to add them.

```
<form action="/StrutsExample/helloWorld.do" method="post">
```

Comment: Tried this...but now it goes to this url `http://localhost/helloworld.do`. How should the action be in struts?